# Function defined in a conditional import in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a conditional import

```
if os.path.exists(SOMEPATH):
    __import__(pymodule)
else:
    sys.exit()
```

I am trying to use functions defined in this  pymodule. But, its giving an error "Undefined Variable"

Comment: Why not use `try` and `except` here?  Seems easier ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__import__()` only imports the module; it does not bind any names.

```
somemodule = __import__(somename)
```